# We need more detailed documentation of BotComposer "match memory scopes"

Tags: botframework

Please, we are developing with new BotComposer and we know there are several memory scopes var that we can use:
[user], for example: "user.surname" is valid if we created previously this var in scope "user"

We know too "turn.recognized.intent" for the last recognized intent...
We know too "dialog.result" if we save a result of a dialog into result...

But what about the others? The predefined or existing values?

· What type of information and how we can obtain all the settings with settings?
· What type of information and how we can obtain all the dialog vars with dialog?

The same for class and this...

We are searching how to obtain current conversationId for example...

Comment: This is exclusively related to BotComposer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for memory can be found in the [Composer docs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/blob/stable/docs/concept-memory.md) and [BotBuilder docs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/adaptive-dialog/docs/memory-model-overview.md).

The BotBuilder docs will probably be most helpful to you. Let me know if those docs answer your questions and feel free to open issues if something is missing or confusing.